# Connecting continuous and discrete data on two different axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I've got data that is continuous for 200 samples and then different results of the same samples but is discrete (Pos, Neg and fail). I thought I could connect the two sets of data using something like `ggpaired` and a secondary axis, but have had no luck. I need a boxplot for the continuous data, but for the discrete, I'd be ok with the data connecting to specific points or groupings on a secondary axis.

Fairly basic, but it gave me roughly what I want just without the separate axis:

```
ggpaired(samples, cond1="discreteresult", cond2="PCRresult", id="sample")
```

But end up with this graph where everything is plotted on the same axis:

[ggpaired_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW2Nt.png)

I thought I could use a secondary axis? But everything I try doesn't seem to allow me to still connect the points? Any other packages I could try? I tried playing with `ggalluvial` but no luck there either. Any help greatly appreciated!

Sample data:

```
sample  discreteresult  PCRresult 
OXPOS.001   Pos 35 
OXPOS.002   Pos 29
OXPOS.003   Pos 25 
OXPOS.004   Pos 28 
OXPOS.005   Pos 31 
OXPOS.006   Pos 25 
OXPOS.007   Pos 32 
OXPOS.008   Pos 26 
OXPOS.009   Pos 28 
OXPOS.010   Pos 29 
OXPOS.011   Pos 35 
OXPOS.012   Neg 32 
OXPOS.013   Neg 35 
OXPOS.014   Neg 26 
OXPOS.015   Neg 30 
OXPOS.016   Neg 30 
OXPOS.017   Fail    27 
OXPOS.018   Fail    41 
OXPOS.019   Fail    12 
OXPOS.020   Neg 22
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(samples)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(samples, 30))`.

Comment: Added the data, apologies!

Comment: The primary author of `ggplot2` is not a fan of using a second axis.  He designed the package to make it extremely difficult to have a second axis unless it is a recode of the first (celsius vs fahrenheit). Expect trouble if you go that route.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for a standard boxplot with the discrete values on the x axis and the continuous values on the y axis?  Like `ggplot(samples, aes(discreteresult, PCRresult)) + geom_boxplot()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I've got a solution, but it's a bit complicated.  First, we have your data:

```
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~sample, ~discreteresult, ~PCRresult, 
  "OXPOS.001","Pos", 35, 
  "OXPOS.002","Pos", 29,
  "OXPOS.003","Pos", 25, 
  "OXPOS.004","Pos", 28, 
  "OXPOS.005","Pos", 31, 
  "OXPOS.006","Pos", 25, 
  "OXPOS.007","Pos", 32, 
  "OXPOS.008","Pos", 26, 
  "OXPOS.009","Pos", 28, 
  "OXPOS.010","Pos", 29, 
  "OXPOS.011","Pos", 35, 
  "OXPOS.012","Neg", 32, 
  "OXPOS.013","Neg", 35, 
  "OXPOS.014","Neg", 26, 
  "OXPOS.015","Neg", 30, 
  "OXPOS.016","Neg", 30, 
  "OXPOS.017","Fail", 27, 
  "OXPOS.018","Fail", 41, 
  "OXPOS.019","Fail", 12, 
  "OXPOS.020","Neg", 22)
```

Next, we would need to figure out where the three dots - positive, negative and fail would go on the same y-axis.  I have them just evenly spaced across (in the object `x` below):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

rg <- range(dat$PCRresult)
x <- rg[1] + diff(rg)/4 * 1:3
```

Then, we make a dataset out of that and merge it with the original data:

```
vals <- tibble(
  discreteresult = c("Pos", "Neg", "Fail"), 
  discreteval = x)
dat <- left_join(dat, vals)
```

Next, we take this new data and re-shape it to be in long format, such that the variable `var` identifies whether the result was a discrete or PCR one.

```
dat2 <- dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c("PCRresult", "discreteval"), 
               names_to="var", 
               values_to = "vals") %>% 
  mutate(var = factor(var, 
                      levels=c("PCRresult", "discreteval"), 
                      labels=c("PCR", "Discrete")))
```

Then, we can make the plot.  The points come from `dat2`.  However, the segments come from the data object before we pivoted to wider.  When the two different sets of `y` points were in different variables.  Then you can specify the second axis which actually is on the same scale as the primary `y` axis, but we specify the appropriate break points and labels for the different point colors.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=dat2, aes(x=var, y=vals, colour=discreteresult), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_segment(data=dat, aes(x=factor(1, levels=1:2, labels=c("PCR", "Discrete")),
                              xend=factor(2, levels=1:2, labels=c("PCR", "Discrete")), 
                              y = PCRresult, yend=discreteval, 
                             colour=discreteresult), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = function(x){x}, breaks=x, labels=c("Positive", "Negative", "Fail"))) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(x="condition", y="Value")
```

[image]

Apologies if I misunderstood the task, but I think this is what you're looking for.

---

**EDIT** - added boxplot

To answer the question in the comments below about adding a boxplot - you can add one.  Basically the trick is to make a boxplot of the PCR points by filtering the `dat2` object to just those containing for `PCR`.  Then you can use that data in the boxplot geometry, which will make a boxplot that sits directly over the PCR points.  You can then use `position = position_nudge(x=-.5)` to shift the boxplot to the left of the points.  I also used `coord_cartesian()` to set the x-limits of the plot.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=dat2, aes(x=var, y=vals, colour=discreteresult), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_segment(data=dat, aes(x=factor(1, levels=1:2, labels=c("PCR", "Discrete")),
                             xend=factor(2, levels=1:2, labels=c("PCR", "Discrete")), 
                             y = PCRresult, yend=discreteval, 
                             colour=discreteresult), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_boxplot(data=filter(dat2, var=="PCR"), 
               aes(x=var, y=vals), 
               position=position_nudge(x=-.5), width=.5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = function(x){x}, breaks=x, labels=c("Positive", "Negative", "Fail"))) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0.75,1.5)) + 
  labs(x="condition", y="Value")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you! I thought I was being naive in that there would be an easy way. 

Though it seems like some data points are missing, less lines and points than data? And any idea how I could add a boxplot to just the left (PCR) data?

Comment: @asherichia Yes, I updated the answer to include the addition of a boxplot.